# Недостатки при подключении css стилей через тег style в шапке?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, webpack

При использовании подхода css in js, у webpack есть плагин style-loader, который грузит стили из js файла, в шапку сайта, в тег . Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие у такого подхода есть недостатки, в сравнении с классическим вариантом, когда стили перемещаются в отдельный css файл, который подключается через link?

Comment: Один из недостатков - отсутствие кеширования.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko кэширование то как раз есть, все стили живут в статичном js файле. Автор немного не правильно написал мысль. В шапку стили вставляет js, шапка html остается пустой. Вообще я тоже задался этим вопросом, но пока до продакшн далеко и я отложил.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, да я видимо действительно не верно описал. Действительно видимо css хранится в js и вместе с ним кешируется. А никто не смотрел, при большом кол-ве css, он не будет слишком долго срабатывать? Ведь получается, что сначала мы получаем js, потом он выполняется, добавляет в style нужные стили, и только после этого они применяются, может это слишком долго? Просто я тоже думаю использовать ли это на проде, и пытаюсь найти подводные камни...